# are years in university considered in graduate admissions

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I'm a 3rd year computer science undergrad in a top 20 (read 10-20) applying to graduate school. Because I simply have less years in college, the papers I'm writing just don't have enough time until they come out. For reference, I am in 2 of the top ~6 CS labs in the school. One of them has a paper coming out soon, although it'll be close and the other has a paper coming out next summer.

Given that I've only been in school for 2.25 years right now and I started in these labs about 0.75 years ago, I think this is fairly reasonable. Will this be taken into account on graduate school admissions or does the committee not care? If the former, should I mention it somehow in my SoP?

Comment: 3 or 4 year degree?

Comment: @nick012000 - 4 year degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People will take relevant information into account, but you should also help them see your side by being explicit in your application materials.

For example, if you are submitting a cover letter or research statement (or similar), you can say something like "over the 9 months in this lab, I have produced research results X and Y that will lead to two upcoming publications." What will matter to the person reading that is what you accomplished in 9 months. If someone is wondering why you've only been doing research for 9 months, they can look at your CV and see that you've only been in college for 2 years.